# Encrypting Disk stuck on "Status: Checking"

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, filevault

I have a Mac mini with 2 disk, and I wanted to encrypt the second (non-boot) disk. I used Finder's right click > Encrypt to start the encryption process. However, it seems to be stuck.

`diskutil cs list` outputs:

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 51...
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Offline
    Size:         0 B (0 B)
    Free Space:   -none-
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 8F...
        ----------------------------------------------------
        Index:    0
        Disk:     disk1s2
        Status:   Checking
        Size:     998999998464 B (999.0 GB)
```

and `diskutil cs info 51...` outputs:

```
Core Storage Properties:
   Role:                       Physical Volume (PV)
   UUID:                       8F...
   Parent LVG UUID:            51...
   Device Identifier:          disk1s2
   PV Size:                    998999998464 B
   PV Status:                  Checking
```

It has been stuck on "Checking" for quite a while, and looking at Activity Monitor shows no processes using CPU or Disk, leading me to believe it has gotten stuck. How can I move forward and get my disk out of this situation?

Edit:
Checking the Console, I keep seeing the message `debugPortal: kCoreStorageGetGroupSparseState invalid lvg uuid` pop up every second.

Edit 2:
The disk has now disappeared from the Finder and Disk Utility, however it still appears in diskutil and diskutil cs, though no diskutil cs commands work, they just say the UUID is invalid.

Comment: How long is "quite a while"? This is one operation you don't want to interrupt until you're absolutely certain it's completely stuck - unless your backup is completely up to date.

Comment: @Tetsujin I do have a backup but I'd like to avoid having to restore if possible. I didn't pay attention to the exact time I started it, but it's been about 2 hours now. I would expect it to be doing at least *something* though, maybe running fsck_hfs or something, but I see absolutely no sign of anything running. Also, see my update on the Console message.